# Refind boot manager will not show Ubuntu splash screen while directly booting the kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, refind

Using a Dell Inspiron 5558 and I need to directly boot the kernel, because GRUB takes too long to load.

How do I get refind to boot with Ubuntu splash screen?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `quiet splash` options to the kernel options. If your installation has a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file, you'd add the options to that file, like this:

```
"Boot with normal options"   "ro root=/dev/mapper/nessus-ubuntu quiet splash"
"Boot with verbose display"  "ro root=/dev/mapper/nessus-ubuntu"
```

The first line includes the relevant option, and the second doesn't. (If you hit F2, Insert, or Tab from rEFInd's main menu, you'll see options for each kernel using each of these lines.)

If your installation doesn't have a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file, you can create one by typing `sudo mkrlconf`. (The `mkrlconf` script comes with rEFInd. Depending on how you installed it, you might need to type the complete path to that script.)